# How can I implement a breadcrumb which contains home state as default then previous state and current state?

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs, ncybreadcrumb

[image]I have a requirement to create a breadcrumb where in, it should look like and function like this,

> Home / Create User / Login

meaning that Home is the default state and create user is the previously visited page and Login is current page. i have tried
`ncyBreadcrumb` but it is not serving my purpose, if any one please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your route/state (depending on whether you use ngRouter/uiRouter), just add a breadcrumb object to it like so:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('courses', {
        url: '/create',
        template: ....,
        controller: ....,
        breadcrumbs: [
         {
          name: Home,
          url: '/home'
         },
         {
          name: Create User,
          url: '/create'
         }
        ]
    })
```

And in your controller, inject `breadcrumbs` as a dependency, and `ng-repeat` over them on your template

```
//Controller
.controller('mycontroller', function mycontroller($scope, breadcrumbs) { 
  $scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
}



//Template
<span class="breadcrumbs">
  <a ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs" ng-bind="::breadcrumb.name" href="{{breadcrumb.url}}"></a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you to respond, will it work when my parent state changed, will it be  possible to get dynamic states as i don't know which state will go next

Comment: in my app I have one main module and few sub modules and in each sub module i have states for each one of them

Comment: even more i am not sure about previous state, which one will be my previous state

Comment: Could you provide a diagram about how your states are laid out? States cannot have a many to many relationship. Each state would have one parent state. If you mean previous URL, then that's a whole other ballgame

Answer (score 0):

> I have used state change success to get current and previous states
>   and it is working same as i need.

**Here is what i did in main module js (in my case app.js):**

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
//goes here your code to manage states and their respective labels
            $rootScope.breadcrumbStates = [];
            $rootScope.breadcrumbLabels = [];
            $rootScope.breadcrumbStates.push(fromState.name);
            $rootScope.breadcrumbStates.push(toState.name);
            $rootScope.breadcrumbLabels.push(fromState.label);
            $rootScope.breadcrumbLabels.push(toState.label);
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbStates track by $index">             
              <a ui-sref="{{breadcrumb}}">{{breadcrumbLabels[$index]}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```